# Cannot inherit undefined extended classes in SuiteCRM

Tags: sugarcrm, suitecrm

We have an external dependency that connects to objects within SuiteCRM (custom objects that extend from SugarBean and Basic) and when we load up the application within our browser, it cannot load the Basic class, presumably because its not called into memory.

Is there a way to load all the required SuiteCRM classes into an external project, if they share the same root directory (e.g, /project is part of the SuiteCRM install)?

Answer (score 0):

if you are accessing this via an external application. I would recommend using the rest / soap API to interface with SuiteCRM.

If you are trying to reuse the classes then you could do the same thing as one of the entry points like index.php, soap.php etc.

They all include entryPoint.php

```
require_once 'include/entryPoint.php';
```